# How to set bootstrap checkbox in razor CheckBoxFor()

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I want to use bootstrap styled checkbox in my asp .net mvc form, however I find it very difficult. After hours looking for solution, I couldn't find anything that works for me.

Here is my HTML razor code, however checkbox doesn't show.

```
                 <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.IsSynchronize, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSynchronize)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is rendered HTML :

```
<div class="checkbox">
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Pole Synchronizacja jest wymagane." id="IsSynchronize" name="IsSynchronize" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="IsSynchronize" type="hidden" value="false">
</div>
```

How can I setup this simple thing in my form?

Comment: What do you mean - doesn't show? Check with F12 in browser that you have `input type="checkbox"` in your rendered html

Comment: Doesn't show - checkbox icon cannot be seen, however when You put mouse over place where it should be, it is there (mouse change icon to hand).

Comment: Looks like css problem, show related css

Comment: And here is element after inspect:

 <div class="checkbox">
                                <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Pole Synchronizacja jest wymagane." id="IsSynchronize" name="IsSynchronize" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="IsSynchronize" type="hidden" value="false">
                            </div>

Comment: I think it is here:     

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after,
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label::after,
.checkbox input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f00c";
}

Comment: Try add type="checkbox" -> `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSynchronize, new { type = "checkbox"})`

Comment: @Perdido it doesn't change anything

I think it is connected with that TextBoxFor creates 2 inputs..

Comment: Hit F12, inspect your checkbox element, copy and paste the final HTML in your question. Also, make sure **bootstrap** `.css` is referenced in your page.

Comment: I updated question as You wished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
                 <div class="form-group">

                     <label class="col-sm-2"></label>
                     <div class="col-sm-10">
                         <div class="checkbox">

                             @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Synchronize)
                             @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Synchronize)
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

its not working because of putting the class in div so add the class in `checkbox` like this

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.IsSynchronize, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSynchronize ,new {@class="checkbox"})
                    </div>
                </div>
```

btw i use `icheck` which are a bit fancy you just have to add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bantikyan/icheck-bootstrap/master/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
```

these libraries in header and in code use

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox icheck-turquoise">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSynchronize)
                @Html.LabelFor(c => c.IsSynchronize, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })


        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Under mvc a true/false checkbox based on the model value (boolean) also has a hidden field with the same name (supposedly to cater for when you don't check the box you still get a value in the Forms collection)

Its this hidden field that stops the checkbox working in bootstrap format.
A bootstrap styled checkbox from what I can see will never display properly under mvc using @Html.CheckBoxFor

This is what i did to get it working

```
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.propertyname" id="[same as property name]" name="[same as property name]" />
            <label for="propertyname">any label you like</label>
        </div>
```

Unfortunately the model isn't updated when you post the form and you have to handle that in the HttpPost'ed action

Answer (score 1):

I used awesome-bootstrap-checkbox, and create checkbox without text like this:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-info checkbox-circle">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PropertyName)
    <label for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.PropertyName)"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to work for me, the checkbox changes shape (the corners round) but acts as though its read only, still working on it.

Just a note to your solution, you could use the offset to keep the controls aligned which don't have labels, so remove

```
<label class="col-sm-2"></label>
```

And add **col-md-offset-2** instead:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-offset-2">
```